# android code to detect if there is any changes in the contents of a folder

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-file

Is there any way that i can detect if there is a change in the contents of a folder which is in android device storage?

i want to detect if the user adds files to that folder, i what to perform some action.How can i do this?

Actually my exact requirement is, whenever the user saves data in my app, i want that to be uploaded to my server. so if there is a change in that specific folder, i'll run the upload activity.
Any help please.

In Short: 
whenever there is a changes in the contents of the folder i what to trigger another event. i want the changes in the folder be the trigger.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `FileObserver` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html. You might need to make it recursive to catch sub-directories

Comment: glad to help (note that FileObserver docs says it's recursive, but i've found that it is not. there are posts here on SO that explain how to make it recursive).